# How to get attributes of dropped object?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I am trying to make Drag'n'drop work between 2 QListWidgets and actually do something with dropped data. For example. I have created such class:

```
class Task(QtGui.QListWidgetItem):
def __init__(self,text,itemid,parent=None,*args):
    QtGui.QListWidgetItem.__init__(self, text,parent, *args)
    self.itemid=itemid
```

And then... I want to access that itemid in dropEvent. Is that possible? Because the only thing I can access in dropEvent is mimeData but it's not very usefull. I was trying to google it but with no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [QDropEvent:source()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdropevent.html#source) to get the widget which was dragged (IMHO your `Task` item, but I don't know python).

Comment: Unfortunatelly .source() is giving TaskListWidget (my class inherited from QListWidget)... so the widget from where item was dragged.. or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure you doing the right thing. But maybe you could use .source() to get your TaskListWidget and use [currentItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#currentItem) to get your QListWidgetItem.